# Combinatorics: How to find the number of sets of numbers in increasing order?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

The problem is the following one:

Let $n$ and $m$ be natural numbers and $m < n$. Find $m$-permutations of the set $\{1, 2,\dots, n\}$ such that permutations are in non-decreasing order (for both cases where repetition is allowed and where it is not allowed).

Tried to solve, still have no ideas.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Aren't we just talking about subsets of size $m$ (by putting the elements in order)? In which case, $\binom{n}{m}$ comes to mind. Do you allow the "$m$-permutation" to have repeats? In this case the answer is $\binom{n+m-1}{m}$: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset#Counting_multisets

Comment: Yes, you are right, we are talking about subsets. There are two parts: the first one is where repetiotions are allowed, and the second, where they are not allowed.

Comment: @SeanEberhard There is an example:
If n = 10 and m = 2, result is 55 (it is stated that it has subtracted 45 from 100 which is the total number of permutations with repetitions allowed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If repetitions are not allowed, then you are interested in counting the number of subsets of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ of size $m$. This is a typical first problem in enumerative combinatorics, with solution (by definition) $\binom{n}{m}$. One can prove $\binom{n}{m} = \frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}$ as follows.

If $\binom{n}{m}$ is the number of subsets of size $m$ from $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, or as you put it, non-decreasing $m$-permutations, then $m!\binom{n}{m}$ is the total number of such $m$-permutations. But these can be counted another way too: there are $n$ ways to choose the first element, $n-1$ ways to choose the second element, ..., and $n-m+1$ ways to choose the $m$th element. We thus find

$$m!\binom{n}{m} = n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-m+1) = \frac{n!}{(n-m)!},$$

so $\binom{n}{m} = \frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}$.

If repetitions are allowed, then you are counting "multisets" of size $m$. The answer turns out to be $\binom{n+m-1}{m}$. This answer can be got as follows. We can choose an $m$-multiset in the following slightly funny way. Imagine $m$ balls in a line. These will be our elements, but they are currently missing names. We will name in them in order, e.g., 11123345555. To do this, we just need to indicate where the "fences" are, i.e., where one label ends and the next begins. There are $m+1$ places for our $n-1$ fences, and so we just have to choose an $(n-1)$-multiset from a set of $m+1$ elements! Interesting though this is, it doesn't help.

Here is a slightly stranger way of choosing where the fences will be. Add $n-1$ more balls to our line, so we have $m+n-1$ balls in all. Now we just have to choose $n-1$ of those balls to turn into fences. Thus the number of $m$-multisets of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ is $\binom{n+m-1}{n-1} = \binom{n+m-1}{m} = \frac{(n+m-1)!}{m!(n-1)!}$

Comment: very comprehensive, thanks

Answer (score 1):

We have a numbers $a_1, ..., a_k$, where ${a_1}\le{a_2}...\le{a_n}$. In this set is ${n}\choose{m}$ options to organize these numbers in non-decreasing order. Each such arrangement may be present $(n-m)!$ times. Count of permutations with non-decreasing order is:
$${{n}\choose{m}}(n-m)!$$

Note: If we search numbers in increasing order:
 If we have numbers $a_1, ..., a_k$, where $k\ge{m}$, taking the number of $a_1$ may be repeated $r_1$ times in set, $a_2$ number $r_2$ times and so on. The $a_1 \lt a_2 \lt ... \lt a_k$. Additionally, $\sum_{i=1}^k{r_i} = n$. In this set is ${k}\choose{m}$ options to organize these numbers in increasing order. Each such arrangement may be present $(n-m)!$. Also, $m\le{n}$. So number of permutations having $m$ numbers in increasing order(${a_1}\lt{a_2}...\lt{a_k}$) is:
$${{k}\choose{m}}(n-m)!$$

Comment: can you please explain a little why we are looking for combinations?

Comment: I overlooked the note in brackets(for both cases where repetition is allowed and where it is not allowed). So I answered only for classical permutations(cases without repetition).I'll add a response.

Comment: thanks, i've understood the point